# Unable to modify volume of AirPods Pro on MacBook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, bluetooth, airpods

I can't modify volume of AirPods Pro on MacBook. The AirPods Pro volume is already set maximum but unable to change it. I have tried different options, reseting AirPods Pro, disconnect and delete it from bluetooth devices. But nothing works. Also AirPods are working fine with iPhone.  Kindly help me out here.
Thank You

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of your audio settings in system preferences?

Comment: Same issue with my AirPods Pro and Macbook M1 1st generation. When i change the volume from menu bar it doesn't change the volume of airpods pro.